# Linking Error for clCreateFromGLTexture Only

Tags: opencl

I am trying to allow OpenCL to render to 2D textures.  I first encountered the function [clCreateFromGLTexture2D](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLTexture2D.html).  I wrote it in, but when I went to compile, I found that it was not defined.  I eventually found it in "cl_gl.h":

```
#ifdef CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_1_APIS
#warning CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_1_APIS is defined. These APIs are unsupported and untested in OpenCL 1.2!
    extern CL_API_ENTRY cl_mem CL_API_CALL
    clCreateFromGLTexture2D(cl_context      /* context */,
                            cl_mem_flags    /* flags */,
                            cl_GLenum       /* target */,
                            cl_GLint        /* miplevel */,
                            cl_GLuint       /* texture */,
                            cl_int *        /* errcode_ret */) CL_EXT_SUFFIX__VERSION_1_1_DEPRECATED;

    extern CL_API_ENTRY cl_mem CL_API_CALL
    clCreateFromGLTexture3D(cl_context      /* context */,
                            cl_mem_flags    /* flags */,
                            cl_GLenum       /* target */,
                            cl_GLint        /* miplevel */,
                            cl_GLuint       /* texture */,
                            cl_int *        /* errcode_ret */) CL_EXT_SUFFIX__VERSION_1_1_DEPRECATED;
#endif /* CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS */
```

So, I looked elsewhere in "cl_gl.h" and I found [clCreateFromGLTexture](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLTexture.html).  In the interest of forward compatibility, I wrote that into the code instead.  However, the function clCreateFromGLTexture causes a LNK2019 (unresolved external).  I find this very suspect, as I CAN compile when using [clCreateFromGLBuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLBuffer.html) and [clCreateFromGLRenderbuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLRenderbuffer.html), and both of these are ALSO in "cl_gl.h".

So, my question: why doesn't clCreateFromGLTexture have a definition, while the functions right next to it in the same module do?  I am currently linking against "OpenCL.lib".  Is there anything else I need?  I didn't see anything.  Is this a problem with the library itself?

[EDIT: clGetDeviceInfo(device_id,CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT,sizeof(cl_bool),&result,NULL); is CL_TRUE, for what it's worth.]

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating the OpenCL libraries to the latest version(`1.2`).

`clCreateFromGLTexture` is defined as part of the OpenCL `1.2` standard, whereas `clCreateFromGLTexture2D` and `clCreateFromGLTexture3D` are part of OpenCL `1.0`. If your OpenCL library is not up to date, you will get an undefined error.

Comment: I'm currently linking against the NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2.  I had assumed that this supported OpenCL 1.2 because of the headers' declaring OpenCL 1.2 functions.  However, in the 4.2 SDK release notes (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/doc/OpenCL_Release_Notes.txt) there's no mention of OpenCL 1.2 support, with the last notes in the change log documenting only OpenCL 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got this error and I had some tough time fixing it. I guess you are using VS2010. 
This may happen for reasons such as:

1. you have not included the reference to the library in the project properties -> linker -> input -> Additional Library dependencies
2. you have compiled the solution as 32bit and using the 64bit library file or vice versa.

Check it out.